# Specify max size for responsive web design

Tags: html, responsive-design

I am just starting out with HTML5. I do understand that using fluid design is an integral part of RWD. So instead of specifying width in px , I am using it in percentage. Have two questions.

1) I find myself creating more breakpoints and specifying different width for each of the points. How to stop this?

2)Also I want to know whether there is any way I can stop the content from resizing after a specified width say after 1024px (58 em) I dont want the application to resize further since the input elements look awkward and stretched beyond this point.

Comment: I dont know why this question was downvoted? Can anyone please explain

Answer (score -1):

If you are just starting with responsive design, you might want to consider using one of the established frameworks like [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) or [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com) ... and there are several other good ones as well.

It will save you heaps of time and questions like those you are asking will be managed by the framework itself.

FWIW, I'm not against roll-your-own solutions to responsive design, but there's so much to learn to get good cross browser/platform results that I think they have a lot going for them and are worth looking at seriously.

Good luck!